# How to extract numeric value from string in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Imagine I have a field of SKU names, and am trying to extract the weight of each SKU into a new column if the field includes the word Ounce (not all of them do). Ideally, I would like the function to return the characters before the word "Ounce", up to the next space character. This should work for all the names in the database. Working with Regex expressions is new to me though and I'm struggling. Can someone help?

I thought I solved the issue with this formula:

REGEXP_SUBSTR(INGREDIENT, '\b([0-9]+) Ounce\b', 1, 1, 'e', 1)

However, it fails when there's a decimal in the SKU name:

Ex: "Sauce - 0.5 Ounce (oz)" returns 5 instead of 0.5.

Apparently there is a PATINDEX function that is useful here but it's not supported by Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `REGEXP_SUBSTR(INGREDIENT,'\\d*\\.?\\d+')`

```
with cte(INGREDIENT) as (
select 'Sauce - 0.5 Ounce (oz)'
union all
select 'Sauce - 12 Ounce (oz)'
)
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(INGREDIENT,'\\d*\\.?\\d+') n
from cte
```

`\\d*` matches zero or more digits

`\\.?` matches a decimal point if there is any

`\\d+` matches one or more digits

Result:

```
0.5
12
```

Comment: If this worked for you can you please mark the above answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it without REGEX. The first three columns just show the steps to get to the result (weight1); the last column (weight2) combines them into a single statement:

```
select c1
,split(upper(c1),' ') arr -- convert string to array split on spaces
,ARRAY_POSITION('OUNCE'::variant, arr) p1 -- get position in array of "OUNCE" (upper case to ensure case comparison is not an issue)
,arr[P1-1]::number(38,4) weight1 -- Get the previous element in the array
,arr[(ARRAY_POSITION('OUNCE'::variant, (split(upper(c1),' '))))-1]::number(38,4) weight2
from values
('Sauce - 0.5 Ounce (oz)') as v1 (c1)
```